Calling a function from one emacsclient can't start Edebug from another emacsclient. Terminal is locked error
I use GNU Emacs 27.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.4, where I use i3 with several emacsclients opened in different terminals, while emacsdaemon is running in background.
After setting Edebug instrumentations into one emacsclient, I cannot start Edebug by calling instrumented function from another emacsclient, it throws the error: Terminal 4 is locked, cannot read from it. On emacsclient that contains into visible buffer function definition that has been instrumented, Edebug works perfectly, even if the function is called from another window of the same emacsclient.
Is there a solution to it?
